# How to load requireJs file only once when a user login and prevent it from loading every time page re-loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, requirejs

I have minified all my js files using require, but require created a minified js file( main.min.js ) which keeps on loading every time page loads and it is slowing down my application. Is there any way i can locally store the minified file in the browser and use it rather requesting for the minified file every time page loads.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way i can locally store the minified file in the browser and use it rather requesting for the minified file every time page loads.

Yes. It's called a *browser cache* and it works without developer intervention (unless [your server explicitly tells the browser to not cache it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49547/575527) or if you use some sort of [cache busting mechanism](http://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-ops-basics/what-is-a-cache-buster-and-how-does-it-work/)).